# `impl Trait` return type causes wrong lifetime elision

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

The `impl Trait` syntax for return types seems to cause the compiler to incorrectly assume that the lifetime of the input argument must match the output in some situations. Consider the function

```rust
fn take_by_trait<T: InTrait>(_: T) -> impl OutTrait {}
```

If the input type contains a lifetime the compiler complains when the output outlives the it even though they are completely independent. This will not happen if the input type is not generic, or if the output is a `Box<dyn OutTrait>`.

Full code:

```rust
trait InTrait {}

struct InStruct<'a> {
    _x: &'a bool, // Just a field with some reference
}

impl<'a> InTrait for InStruct<'a> {}

trait OutTrait {}

impl OutTrait for () {}

fn take_by_type(_: InStruct) -> impl OutTrait {}

fn take_by_trait<T: InTrait>(_: T) -> impl OutTrait {}

fn take_by_trait_output_dyn<T: InTrait>(_: T) -> Box<dyn OutTrait> {
    Box::new(())
}

fn main() {
    let _ = {
        let x = true;
        take_by_trait(InStruct{ _x: &x }) // DOES NOT WORK
        // take_by_type(InStruct { _x: &x }) // WORKS
        // take_by_trait_output_dyn(InStruct { _x: &x }) // WORKS
    };
}
```

Is there some elided lifetime here that I could qualify to make this work, or do I need to do heap allocation?

Comment: Adding a `'static` bound with `impl OutTrait + 'static` does not help either. AFAIK, it should have made it so the return value would be bound to a `'static` lifetime and no longer depend on the input lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`impl Trait` in return position implicitly captures the any lifetime appearing in generic parameters. This is not something you can express in normal Rust, only with `impl Trait`.

On stable as far as I know there is no way to avoid that. On nightly you can use `type_alias_impl_trait`:

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

type Ret = impl OutTrait;
fn take_by_trait<T: InTrait>(v: T) -> Ret {}
```

See issues [Unclear compiler error when impl Trait return value captures non-'static argument (#82171)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82171), [impl Trait capturing lifetime of type parameter (#79415)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/79415), [False-positive "temporary dropped while borrowed" involving return-position impl Trait (#98997)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/98997), [impl Trait + 'static is not static if returned from generic function (#76882)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76882).

Answer (score 3):

The `impl Trait` semantic means that the function returns some type that implements the `Trait`, but the caller cannot make any assumptions about which type that would be or what lifetimes it would use.

For all the compiler knows the `take_by_trait` function can be used in many different modules, or, probably, in other crates. Now, your implementation would work fine in all use cases. It can be rewritten like

```rust
fn take_by_trait<T: InTrait>(_: T) -> () {}
```

This is a perfectly fine function and will work just fine. But then at some point you might want to add another implementation for the `OutTrait` and change your `take_by_trait` function a little.

```rust
trait OutTrait { fn use_me(&self) {} }
impl<T: InTrait> OutTrait for T {}

fn take_by_trait<T: InTrait>(v: T) -> impl OutTrait {v}
```

If we expand the generic parameter and `impl` definition, we get this code:

```rust
fn take_by_trait<'a>(v: InStruct<'a>) -> InStruct<'a> {v}

fn main() {
    let v = {
        let x = true;
        take_by_trait(InStruct{ _x: &x })
    };
    
    v.use_me();
}
```

This obviously cannot work because `x` is dropped before `println!` tries to access its value. So by adding a new implementation for the `OutTrait` you broke code that uses this function, potentially somewhere in a crate that depends on yours. That's why the compiler is reluctant to allow you defining such things.

So, again, the issue with `impl OutTrait` is just that the compiler cannot make any assumptions about the returned type and its lifetime, so it uses the maximum possible bound, which produces the borrow checker error you see.

EDIT: I've modified the code a little so that the signature of the function would not change and the code actually compiles and produces the same lifetime error: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d43182316e641694e78c36ee17b3dca)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Do you know of any way to get around this? As @kushagra-gupta mentioned, adding `+ 'static` to the return value doesn't seem to affect anything. 

Can the return value be written with a generic instead of `impl OutTrait` so lifetimes can be specified? 
```rust
fn take_by_trait<T: InTrait, U: OutTrait>(_: T) -> U {}
```
doesn't seem to be valid syntax.

Comment: So far I couldn't come up with a solution to this. Using `take_by_trait_output_dyn` might be the only possible solution. Or writing the concrete type instead of `impl Trait` in case you return an iterator or something similar, not a closure.

Comment: If a function returns a value containing references, the lifetime of those references _**MUST**_ be either `'static` or connected to one of the arguments.